# SQL Server query help... super slow query

Tags: sql-server

My query is taking too long to execute, do anyone know how to optimize the query below? P.S. The 'temp_db' has 1'024'912'779 rows.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Mobile%' 
          THEN 'Mobile' 
          ELSE 'Desktop' 
    END AS DEVICE,
    CAST(DATEADD(hour, +8, timestamp_gmt) AS Date) AS HKDate,
    DATEPART(Hour, DATEADD(hour, +8, timestamp_gmt)) AS HKHour,
    pixel_name AS Pixel,
    COUNT(id) AS Fires,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS Uu
FROM
    temp_db
WHERE
    CONVERT(date, timestamp_gmt) BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()) 
                                     AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
    AND advertiser_name LIKE '%TimCompany%'
GROUP BY
    CASE 
       WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Mobile%' 
          THEN 'Mobile' 
          ELSE 'Desktop' 
    END, 
    CAST(DATEADD(hour, +8, timestamp_gmt) AS Date),
    DATEPART(Hour, DATEADD(hour, +8, timestamp_gmt)),
    pixel_name;
```

Comment: Two things that might slow you down: **(1)** can you try to take out the two  `COUNT(...)` statements - does that help? **(2)** a `LIKE '%......%`` with a leading `%` is **always** going to do a full table scan - can you rewrite this condition to something else that can exist *without* a leading `%` in a `LIKE` condition? Otherwise, have a look at the actual **execution plan** to see where the time goes ..

Comment: In addition to marc_s I'd change the `CONVERT(date, timestamp_gmt)` to `CAST(timestamp_gmt AS DATE)`, which should be sargable. I'm not sure about `CONVERT` and sargability...

Comment: Try to eliminate the functions within your WHERE condition.

Comment: Great advices guys, took out the leading % and use CAST instead of CONVERT. Now the query is greatly improved, however, still took me over 10 mins to run even using the queries from cloudsafe and JaydipJ below. Am I reaching the maximum efficiency of SQL server?

Comment: @atsang01 Which indexes are there? The row count is rather huge... Indexes will make a very big deal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : below script minimize the repetitive same function calls

```
SELECT DEVICE,
       HKDate,
       HKHour,
       Pixel
       COUNT(ID) Fires,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ID) Uu
FROM ( 
        SELECT
              CASE WHEN user_agent like '%Mobile%' THEN 'Mobile' ELSE 'Desktop' END AS DEVICE,
              CAST(DATEADD(hour,+8,timestamp_gmt) AS Date) AS HKDate,
              DATEPART(Hour,DATEADD(hour, +8, timestamp_gmt)) AS HKHour,
              pixel_name AS Pixel,
              ID
        FROM  temp_db
        WHERE  CONVERT(date,timestamp_gmt) BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) AND
       advertiser_name like '%TimCompany%'
)M
GROUP BY DEVICE,HKDATE,HKHOUR,pixel
```

Comment: Hi @JaydipJ, can I know the difference between select table "inside" FROM and outside "FROM"? What would that impact the running speed?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @atsang01, As you can find difference in both versions of query, in you query you used same function that are present in both select and group by statement, in above version I reduce that UN-necessary function calls from group by clause by making derived table. did u tried above script?

Comment: Yes, your query is much faster. I also replaced CONVERT to CAST inside the WHERE clause, which greatly improved the running time (5:30 using CONVERT and 3:40 using CAST(timestamp_gmt AS DATE). Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The date in where clause is not sargable. try below:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Mobile%' 
          THEN 'Mobile' 
          ELSE 'Desktop' 
    END AS DEVICE,
    CAST(DATEADD(hour, +8, timestamp_gmt) AS Date) AS HKDate,
    DATEPART(Hour, DATEADD(hour, +8, timestamp_gmt)) AS HKHour,
    pixel_name AS Pixel,
    COUNT(id) AS Fires,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS Uu
FROM
    temp_db
WHERE
    timestamp_gmt >= convert(date, DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()))
                 and timestamp_gmt < convert(date, DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) )
    AND advertiser_name LIKE '%TimCompany%'
GROUP BY
    CASE 
       WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Mobile%' 
          THEN 'Mobile' 
          ELSE 'Desktop' 
    END, 
    CAST(DATEADD(hour, +8, timestamp_gmt) AS Date),
    DATEPART(Hour, DATEADD(hour, +8, timestamp_gmt)),
    pixel_name;
```

Comment: Tried!! Now the execution time improved to 11mins, is that acceptable?

Comment: If you can take the % from before or after TimCompany it would help, depending on the nature of the data.